# Get image from specified path in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, file

I need to load an image from a specified path on my local hard drive and store it in a variable so that I can send it to an API. I CANNOT use a file browser to select an image, I CANNOT use an input field, it must be done automatically.

All the solutions I've found are done by getting it from an HTML input field but I need to get the image directly from my hard drive instead. How can I do this?

Comment: If I get you correct, you are expecting your TypeScript code to access files from your hard drive without any user intervention. Is that so?

Comment: @atiyar yes, that's right.

Comment: In a browser? That's impossible due to security concerns

Comment: No, in an angular app.